# React: Unexpected token, expected (

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component and i am trying to render a list of string words inside it. I have the words in an array and i can apply `map` on it. The problem is, I want to set an index as key for every object in the list.
Here is the component:

```
export default class RandomWords extends Component{

  var ID=-1;
  createWord(word){
    ID++;
    return ({
      id:ID,
      text:word
    });

  }

    renderList(){

      return this.props.words.map((word)=>{
          const wrappedText=this.createWord(word);
          return (<li key={wrappedText.id}  className="item">
                  <Word value={wrappedText.text}></Word>
          </li>);
       })
    }
      render(){
      //  console.log("words are:"+this.props.words);
          return(
                  <ul className="list">
                      {this.renderList()}
                </ul>)
      };
}
```

To generate the id, I have seen [this](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318#.a2a04fgj2), and i made the  `createWord(word)` function, but in the line `var ID=-1;` it complains with:

```
 Unexpected token, expected (
```

**1-What is wrong with my code?**

**2-How can i set integer number starting from 0 to the list?**

Comment: you can't put a `var` free floating in a class like that.. think of `class` like a regular javascript object in that sense, it's a list key values where the values are functions. put the `var` above your class definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can't have `var`s free floating like that. Regardless, a better solution is to use the built in index of `map`. Since this is a generator function, the second argument is the index, therefore, you can change your logic to:

```
return this.props.words.map((word, i)=>{
  return (<li key={i}  className="item">
      <Word value={word}></Word>
  </li>);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only put methods in ES6 classes. Instead, rewrite your class like this:

```
export default class RandomWords extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ID = -1;
  }

  createWord(word){
    this.ID++;
    return ({
      id: this.ID,
      text: word
    });

  }
  // ...
}
```

---

or, if you want `ID` to be globally incremented across all instances:

```
let ID = -1;
export default class RandomWords extends Component {

  createWord(word){
    ID++;
    return ({
      id: ID,
      text: word
    });

  }
  // ...
}
```